# Understanding share() in Combine

Tags: swift, combine

As we know, usually publishers are struct. What will change if it is a class?

Let's consider we have 1 publisher which emits 1 value and 2 subscribers, which subscribes to it.

```
let p1 = Just(20)
let s1 = p1.print().sink { _ in }
let s2 = p1.print().sink { _ in }

// s1 - receive value: (20)
// s2 - receive value: (20)
```

in print logs, we can see that both subscribers got value (20).

If we open the documentation of share() operator, we will see

> share() - Returns a publisher as a class instance.

So it just changes semantic of the publisher from value to reference. In our example, we don't pass `p1` publisher to any function or assign to any object and that's why for me there is no difference publisher is struct or class ...
But if I add `share()` operator behavior will be different, `s2` won't get value.

```
let p1 = Just(20).share() // !
let s1 = p1.print().sink { _ in }
let s2 = p1.print().sink { _ in }

// s1 - receive value: (20)
```

I saw some examples with `URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(\_: URL)` or with some "delayed" publishers, when `s2` also gets value, but it's still unclear for me how just changing semantic of publisher change its behaviour in such way.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using a pipeline where it *does* make a difference. Consider this example (based on a Cocoa With Love article) where a second subscriber comes online after the publisher has been publishing for some time:

```
let pub1 = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .default)
let c1 = pub1.connect()
let scan = Publishers.Scan(upstream: pub1, initialResult: 0) { (a, b) -> Int in
    a + 1
}
scan.sink { print("a:", $0) }.store(in:&storage)
delay(3) {
    scan.sink { print("b:", $0) }.store(in:&self.storage)
}
```

The point is, there is only one `scan` and it is producing 1, 2, 3 when after a delay another subscriber comes along. What will that subscriber get? Will it just pick up where we are now? No. We get this:

```
a: 1
a: 2
a: 3
a: 4
b: 1
a: 5
b: 2
a: 6
b: 3
...
```

So in effect we start all over again with our second subscription, because the publisher is a new copy. But if we promote the publisher to a class, we get completely different results:

```
let pub1 = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .default)
let c1 = pub1.connect()
let scan = Publishers.Scan(upstream: pub1, initialResult: 0) { (a, b) -> Int in
    a + 1
}
let scan2 = scan.share() // <--
scan2.sink { print("a:", $0) }.store(in:&storage)
delay(3) {
    scan2.sink { print("b:", $0) }.store(in:&self.storage)
}
```

Now we get this:

```
a: 1
a: 2
a: 3
a: 4
b: 4
a: 5
b: 5
a: 6
b: 6
a: 7
b: 7
```

Obviously that's a very significant difference. You can see the same sort of thing if your publisher is a Subject, because that's a class, not a struct.

Answer (score 3):

In my option, if you don't add `.share()`, there will be ***two*** event streams subscribed by two subscribers. If you add `.share()`, there will be only ***one*** event stream subscribed by two subscribers.